# Generating text features with spacy consumes too much time

Tags: python-3.x, feature-extraction, spacy, nlp

I am extracting text features like noun count from text. The following function is consuming too much time. How can I optimize this?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

def get_numeric_features(df):    

    df['NOUN_COUNT'] = df.apply(lambda x: len([token.pos_ for token in nlp(x['TITLE_TEXT']) if token.pos_ == 'NOUN']),axis=1)

    return df

start = time.time()
df1 = get_numeric_features(df1)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

df1.head()
```

Time it took (around 23 mins for 130000 rows)

```
1415.4789326190948
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only thing you want from spacy is POS tagging. You can gain some time if you disable paring and entity recognition.

In spacy 1.x:

```py
nlp = spacy.load('en', parser=False, entity=False)
```

In spacy 2.x:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['ner', 'parser'])
```

I don't know what data structure your `df` is and what `.apply` does, but you can, of course, try to gain some speedup via some parallelization.